# Display the message written in log file on webpage after every 3 seconds

Tags: java, servlets, logging

So i have built an web application which perform a task which may take upto 10 minutes. 
I want to show the current status to user on the webpage.

I have `log.info(), log.debug() and log.error()` message used within my webapp for logging the status.

How should i go about displaying the log message on webpage using minimum effort. ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at extending log4j classes http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html

In you custom loggers you can also write to the web page as well as keeping normal log4j functionality and configuration.

Comment: I have to display it in a textarea how can i do that ?

Comment: Without reloading the page

Comment: jquery and ajax - call a servlet